# How to print >null 2>&1 to file

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to execute:

```
echo reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v DisableOSUpgrade /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f >nul 2>&1 >%path%
```

In output file i get all execpt `>nul 2>&1`.

How can I escape > carracter? I tryed with ^ or \ but nothing works. If I quote whole echo without >%path% I'll get all in the output but and quotes too.

Comment: `^>nul 2^>^&1` should work. I hope you're not actually using a variable named `path`. Windows environment variables are case insensitive.

Comment: oh I forgot to escape & character. Thank you!